# Uploading a CSV with React and ASP.NET Core API endpoint accepting an IFormFile gives 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object' error

Tags: c#, reactjs, csv, asp.net-core, iformfile

I've created an endpoint that takes a CSV file, parses it (with the help of CsvHelper), does some conversions, and then persists that data to my SQL Server database. I'm able to pass a CSV file in just fine through the API, but I'm encountering an issue with getting this endpoint hooked up to my React front-end to where I can upload the CSV through the UI and call the endpoint to do the rest of the work. A 400: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object' error is being thrown instead. I've looked through a ton of SO posts that had a similar issue to mine and have tried the solutions, but none of them have worked for my situation.

FileModel Class:

```
public class FileModel
{
    public IFormFile FormFile { get; set; }
}
```

Upload Endpoint:

```
// I have these attributes here since the CSVs I will be uploading are pretty large.
[DisableRequestSizeLimit]
[RequestFormLimits(MultipartBodyLengthLimit = 234217728)]
[HttpPost("Upload")]
public async Task<ActionResult> CsvUpload([FromForm] FileModel file)
{
    // Endpoint does the parsing and persisting here...
}
```

I don't believe the issue lies in what I'm doing within the endpoint so I left that out, but please let me know if it's needed.

React.js:

```
const reqHeaders = { 
                headers: {
                    'Accept': 'application/json, application/octet-stream, application/csv, text/plain, application/x-www-form-urlencoded, multipart/form-data, text/csv, */*',
                },
            }
            let formData = new FormData()
            formData.append('file', new Blob([fileSelector.current.files[0]]))
            apiCalls.post("https://localhost:44323/api/MyController/Upload", formData, reqHeaders).then((res) => {
                console.log(res)
                setShowSnackbarSuccess(true)
                setSnackbarMessage(`Successfully uploaded the data.`)
            }).catch((e) => {
                console.error(e)
                setShowSnackbarError(true)
                setSnackbarMessage('Failed to upload the data.')
            }).finally(() => {
                setShowBusyDialog(false)
                setShowUploadProgressModal(false)
                fileSelector.current.value = null
            })
```

Does a file name need to be appended to the FormData object, or does something need to be added to the headers? I'm not quite sure at this point if this is an issue on the front-end of the back-end so any insight on why the error is being thrown is most appreciated. Also, the React code is not my code, but my partner's, so I'll try to answer the best I can on it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Does this method:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> CsvUpload([FromForm] FileModel file)
{
    // Endpoint does the parsing and persisting here...
}
```

reside in a controller that inherits : ControllerBase ?

If so, perhaps you don't even need [FromForm] FileModel file

the following code should be able to handle uploaded text files:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> CsvUpload()
{
    var uploadedFiles = this.HttpContext.Request.Form.Files;
    foreach (var uploadedFile in uploadedFiles) 
    {
       string fileFullPath = @"../sometempfolder/tempfile.txt";
       if (System.IO.File.Exists(fileFullPath))
          System.IO.File.Delete(fileFullPath);

       using (FileStream stream = System.IO.File.Open(fileFullPath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
           {
                 await uploadedFile.CopyToAsync(stream);
           }
          string csvContents = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(fileFullPath);
          // ProcessCSVFile(csvContents);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, the controller that endpoint is in does inherit from ControllerBase. It looks like I'll have to rearrange a few things in my endpoint without that parameter. With this change in the endpoint, is there anything I would have to change in my React code? Thanks!

Comment: a plain ajax would look like this (partly - this comment box won't let me put the whole code): var formData = new FormData(); formData.append('file', file, file.name); let xHRObject = new XMLHttpRequest();xHRObject.open('POST', urlToPost, true);xHRObject.send(formData);

Comment: As long as you post FormData object and that FormData object contains files, your c# code should be able to pickup this.HttpContext.Request.Form.Files. Also it should be able to pickup other form values that are not files

Comment: Whose file system this code is accessing? it looks like the file and the server where this API will be hosted are same? please clarify. What if the system where the .csv is present is different from the one where API is hosted. In that case we'll need to use something like impersonation for accessing the CSV file related system ?

Comment: Typically the web application would upload file to a folder where the application is hosted on. I think the objective here is to be able to upload the file to the server. Once the file is in the server, then it is up to us what to do with it. We could have the application copy it to a network drive, invoke httpclient call to upload it to another server, invoke ftp to transfer it with ftp protocol to another server, execute an external program to process that file, call an smtp function to email that file, have a scheduled task to take care of that file. The possibilities are endless.